# which xml tag changing the launch image

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, xml

I convert my HTML, CSS, JS file in apk file. So I have the app on my phone, but I want to change the default launch image, so when I open the app the launch image is the default image.

Can somebody help me, what I should add to my XML file to change the image?

```
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8' ?>
<widget
    android-versionCode = '1'
    id = 'com.TicTacToe.funny'
    version = '1.0.0'
    xmlns = 'https://www.w3.org/ns/widgets'>
    <icon  src="tic-tac-toe.png"/>

    <name>Tic Tac Toe</name>
    <description>Tic Tac Toe game</description>


    <preference name = 'orientation' value = 'portrait'/>
     
</widget>
```